# How to run a webpack plugin after another?

Tags: webpack, postcss, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, postcss-loader

I have the files:

```css
/* variables.scss */

:root {
    --color: red;
}

/* button.scss */

.color {
    color: var(--color);
}
```

And I import then in JS:

```js
/* index.js */

import "./variavles.scss";
import "./button.scss";
```

I'm using [postcss-cssnext](https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext) to replace the variables with it's values, But using it with [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) doesn't work because there are two separate files so `postcss` loose the context of the variables: (https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext/issues/418#issuecomment-334056406).

So my question is: Is there a way to only call the `postcss` plugin after all file are concatenated into one?